# Code First Migration change string into datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

There was property in my **Task** model
`public string DateTarget { get; set; }`
I created database (I use code first approach)
then I need to change this property 
like

```
private DateTime _dateTarget;
public DateTime DateTarget
    {
        get { return _dateTarget; }
        set
        {
            _dateTarget = value.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) != string.Empty ? value : DateTime.MinValue;
        }
    }
```

I used this commands in PM Console

Enable-Migrations
Add-Migration UpdateDB
Update-Database

but I got an error

`Error Number:241,State:1,Class:16
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time
from character string.`

What's wrong? How to fix it?